# Rails - different Time.now in controller \ test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, integration-testing

i m working on app from Agile WD with ROR 4.0.

i got a an order receive_date in my order_controller, and an integration test that checks it. Controller creates an order, test checks that date and time is same. And the difference is 1 day and 3 hours for some reason? how is that possible, using same function to get date in both cases.here's the test, followed by controller and test output:

Test:

```
test "buying a product" do
  LineItem.delete_all
  Order.delete_all
  ruby_book = products(:ruby)
  get"/"
  assert_response :success
  assert_template "index"
  xml_http_request :post, '/line_items', product_id: ruby_book.id
  assert_response :success
  cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  assert_equal 1, cart.line_items.size
  assert_equal ruby_book, cart.line_items[0].product
  get"/orders/new"
  assert_response :success
  assert_template "new"
  receive_date_expected = Time.now.to_date
  post_via_redirect "/orders",
    order: { name: "Dave Thomas",
             address: "123 TheStreet",
             email: "dave@example.com",
             pay_type: "Check"}
  assert_response :success
  assert_template "index"
  cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  assert_equal 0, cart.line_items.size
  orders = Order.all
  assert_equal 1, orders.size
  order = orders[0]
  assert_equal "Dave Thomas", order.name
  assert_equal "123 TheStreet", order.address
  assert_equal "dave@example.com", order.email
  assert_equal "Check", order.pay_type
  assert_equal receive_date_expected, order.receive_date.to_date
  assert_equal 1, order.line_items.size
  line_item = order.line_items[0]
  assert_equal ruby_book, line_item.product
  mail = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
  assert_equal ["dave@example.com"], mail.to
  assert_equal 'Sergey Sob <j0nybr4v0@gmail.com>', mail[:from].value
  assert_equal "Pragmatic Store Order Confirmation", mail.subject
end
```

controller:

```
def create
@order = Order.new(params[:order])
@order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)
@order.receive_date = Time.now.to_date
respond_to do |format|
  if @order.save
    Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
    session[:cart_id] = nil
    OrderNotifier.received(@order).deliver
    format.html { redirect_to store_url, notice: 'Thank you for your order' }
    format.json { render json: @order, status: :created, location: @order }
  else
    @cart = current_cart
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

and here's the output:

```
 1) Failure:
test_buying_a_product(UserStoriesTest) [c:/Ruby193/work/depot/test/integration/u
ser_stories_test.rb:44]:
<Wed, 30 May 2012> expected but was
<Tue, 29 May 2012>.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try comparing them as UTC. Call `#utc` on them and then check. Any difference? Do be absolutely sure you can always call `#zone` on them and see if they match.

Comment: thanks, but...how exactly do i do it? i m complete noob in rails and code here differs SO MUCH from java\c i m used to. have no idea how to implement your tip...:(

Comment: You could always assert the timezone equality temporary would by adding this to your current test.

`assert_equal Time.now.zone, order.receive_date.zone`

Does this assertion pass or does it throw an exception?

Comment: now it says my zone is expected but is nil? wtf...
changed the receive_date in controller to Time.now.zone

Comment: Don't do that. Revert your changes to what you had before. Add the assertion above to your unit test. Run the test and see it fail. Does the added assertion fail or does it pass? If it fails, please send the response. Make sure you add my assertion before the failing one.

Comment: ok, i understand. did what you said.here's new output:
<"Jerusalem Daylight Time"> expected but was
<"UTC">.

Comment: As you can see it was a time zone issue. Change your past assertion to the following `assert_equal receive_date_expected.utc.to_date, order.receive_date.utc.to_date`. Be sure to also change `receive_date_expected = Time.now.to_date` to `receive_date_expected = Time.now` instead. You can remove my previous assertion also.

Comment: that actually worked!!! thanks a ton, mate :)
PS - may be u have any idea how the simple way to do this(original code) didn't work, what's the reason? i d really like to understand that to know what goes behind the scenes, not just copy\paste code...thanks in advance

Comment: The reason your original code didn't work was because of the different time zones. One of your time objects had Jerusalem Daylight Time as time zone and the other was in UTC. When you called `.to_date` on those objects you got string representations of them and those was different.

Comment: of course, but i used same command, just inside different files(controller\test), so why would it assign different values? thats what i struggle to understand.
i mean, a = 5, would be 5 in both files, right...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some kind of timezone problem.

Try to replace `Time.now` by `Time.zone.now` everywhere, it may help.

Comment: same :( i doubt that its time zone, even dates differ...absolutely clueless here :/

Comment: Oh, dates of course can differ, and I don't see any other possible reasons besides this. But maybe specifically my solution didn't work...